# Problema com JSON de tamanho grande no android

Tags: java, android, json

Estou recebendo um arquivo JSON de um WebService, esse arquivo vem com o tamanho aproximado de 5.7M, ai quando eu vou converter seu conteúdo para JsonArray usando a biblioteca Gson, ele me apresenta o erro:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 4045314

porém o arquivo está correto, quando gero o mesmo arquivo com uma quantidade de conteúdo um pouco menor (1.8M) á rotina funciona normalmente, alguém tem conhecimento do porque isso ocorre, há alguma solução conhecida ?

Segue o código utilizado:

```
 JsonParser  parser = new JsonParser();
 JsonElement elem   = parser.parse( json.getString("webservice") ); //O erro ocorre aqui;
 JsonArray resultado2 = elem.getAsJsonArray();
 int len = resultado2.size();
```

---

Galera, peço desculpas a todos. Encontrei o problema. O arquivo estava vindo corrompido não baixava completamente, quando eu verifiquei o arquivo tinha visto o que o sistema me gerava, não o que o tablet baixava.

Peço desculpas e agradeço o apoio de todos aqui.

Comment: Já tentou usar essa biblioteca http://www.json.org/java/?

Comment: Sim, era a que eu usava antes e dava um erro semelhante, por isso tentei com a gson pois vi que resolveu alguns casos.

Comment: Para performance eu recomendo a biblioteca do `Jackson`, para Android tem a `jackson-jr` (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jr).

Comment: posta o código que tu tá usando para converter. Ele pode ser otimizado.

Comment: Pronto editei a pergunta e coloquei o código, @Wakim estou lendo sobre ela agora.

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de você pensar em paginar este arquivo?

Comment: Então, eu também faria o mesmo OnoSendai só que não é meu o arquivo vem de outro sistema, e eles não podem fazer nada para me paginar o arquivo pois o serviço é utilizado por outras aplicações.

Comment: @HiagoSouza Você tem à sua disposição um servidor? Uma possibilidade seria implementar lá um parser que faça a paginação para você.

Comment: Então, o objetivo é utilizar o recurso existente para as outras aplicações, ou seja o mesmo servidor fornece as informações as demais aplicações, porém se eu precisar alocar um servidor só para fazer isso o projeto vai ficar inviável ('caro') para o cliente final. Estou tentando fazer o procedimento todo no tablet e para finalizar só precisaria acabar essa parte. Ele convertendo para o objeto acredito que o resto da rotina vai funcionar normalmente. Obs: estou testando o StringReader que o @Eduardo Oliveira enviou. Fico de dar uma resposta a vocês assim que acabar.

Comment: Não havia um erro de programação real.

Comment: Não, não havia @utluiz.

Answer (score 0):

Vou dar um chute, não sei se irá resolver.

O método parse também aceita um Reader como parâmetro. Tente encapsular o String em um StringReader e então fazer o parse:

```
JsonParser  parser = new JsonParser();

StringReader reader = new StringReader(json.getString("webservice"));

JsonElement elem   = parser.parse(reader);
JsonArray resultado2 = elem.getAsJsonArray();
int len = resultado2.size();
```

Comment: Vou tentar, obrigado. Já venho dizer se funcionou.

Comment: tentei sua sugestão porém agora ele cai no catch e o Exeception vem como "null".

Comment: No seu código original, onde exatamente acontecia o erro? Aqui `json.getString("webservice")` ou aqui `parser.parse(...)`?

Comment: no parser.parse. JsonElement elem   = parser.parse(...);

Comment: Não faz muito sentido isso. Você consegue colar o conteúdo do json gerado no site jsonlint.com? Vamos garantir que o conteúdo está ok. :)

Comment: Tentei e lá não consigo colar, pois é muito grande o arquivo, ai eu tentei validar pelo http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ que ele pega pela url. E nele está tudo ok.

Comment: Será que poderia de alguma forma estar estourando a memória ?

Comment: E se você tentasse ler diretamente do stream? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902425/load-very-heavy-stream-with-gson

Comment: Acredito que está acontecendo é que está estourando a memória.